# How to restrict VueX store access to certain pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

I have a Vuex store that has a list of blog posts, and about three pages have access to that store. When I run npm run generate, the build size ends up being huge because all the other pages also have the Vue store's state included in their static files even though they aren't using the store. For the app, it is using SSR.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within asyncData of the pages that need the store modules:

```
asyncData (context) {
  context.store.registerModule('moduleName', () => import('/path/to/modules/file'))
}
```